# AWS DynamoDB bulk update on 2 fields for all entries using AWS CLI and unix script

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I have table similar to this:

[image]

And am using the AWS CLI, specifically:

```
appId="ABC"
aws dynamodb update-item \
            --table-name XTable \
            --key "{\"appId\":{\"S\":\"${appId//[$'\t\r\n ']}\"}}"  \
            --update-expression "SET startDate = :sd, endDate = :ed" \
            --expression-attribute-values '{":sd": {"S": "14/11/2020 23:30:00"}, ":ed": {"S": "15/11/2020 01:17:00"}}' \
            --return-values ALL_NEW
```

At the moment, I can do a scan and iterate over the entries like so:

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name XTable--query "Items[*].[appId.S]" --output text
```

However, is there way to do an update for multiple keys instead?

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB doesn't offer an api to **Update** multiple items in one request.
You have to specify the full key of all the items that you want to update.

You can exploit [BatchWriteItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html) that allows to **Put** and **Delete** multiple elements in one request.

Notice that **PutItem** is used for writing an item to a table and this can completely overwrite an existing item with the same key, if any.

You can also exploit [transactions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TransactWriteItems.html) if you want that all of your reads or writes will succeed or fail together.

BatchWrite or Transactions categories are used for reading and writing multiple DynamoDB items in a single request. While these operate on multiple items at once, they are still item-based actions because you must specify the exact items on which you want to operate.

My suggestion is to scan the table and for each result you apply an update item.

The DynamoDB API may seem limited, but it’s very intentional. The key point to understand about DynamoDB is that it won’t let you write a bad query.

Comment: thanks for replying, however I was looking for a way to just specify the fields that I need to update the values on, looks like the BatchWriteItem requires to have the full data to be written ie. if the table had 5 other columns that should be unchanged, I would have to specify those even though they are the same values. I just posted my solution using the for loop but my concern about it is the multiple execution calls

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented it using scan then loop for each entry. However, this means if there are 100 entries in the table, it will do a update call 100 times.
I was looking for a way to save on the 100 calls if possible to just execute 1 update call with all the keys especially since the values to be updated is the same dates?

This is the solution I have that I am asking if there's an alternative way to save up the multiple calls:

```
#!/bin/bash 
for appId in $(aws dynamodb scan --table-name XTable --query "Items[*].[applicationId.S]" --output text) ;
do
    echo "start updating $appId"
    aws dynamodb update-item \
        --table-name XTable \
        --key "{\"appId\":{\"S\":\"${appId//[$'\t\r\n ']}\"}}"  \
        --update-expression "SET startDate = :sd, endDate = :ed" \
        --expression-attribute-values '{":sd": {"S": "01/01/2020 03:30:00"}, ":ed": {"S": "15/01/2020 11:00:00"}}' \
        --return-values ALL_NEW     
    echo "completed $appId"         
done
```

Comment: How to run this script in power shell?

Comment: $appIds = aws dynamodb scan --table-name XTable --query "Items[*].[applicationId.S]" --output text

foreach ($appId in $appIds.Split()) {
    Write-Host "start updating $appId"

    aws dynamodb update-item `
        --table-name XTable `
        --key "{\"appId\":{\"S\":\"$($appId.Trim())\"}}" `
        --update-expression "SET startDate = :sd, endDate = :ed" `
        --expression-attribute-values '{":sd": {"S": "01/01/2020 03:30:00"}, ":ed": {"S": "15/01/2020 11:00:00"}}' `
        --return-values ALL_NEW

    Write-Host "completed $appId"
}